# php encoding and decoding string

Tags: php, mysql

I have an app where users can upload an image to be used as their avatar. The way is set things up are as follows. There's a folder named **"Uploads"** and when the user selects an image it gets uploaded and stored there and renamed to the user's username then a reference in the database is made referring to that image, so the string in the database will look like this

**" ../uploads/username.jpg"** 
I am using PHP's `rawurlencode();` function to handle user names with spaces in them, such as **"User admin"** so when this user uploads a picture it will be stored in the database like this **../uploads/user%20admin.jpg** now when I wanna display that image i'm using `rawurldecode();` function but it just isn't working properly as it's decoding in this manner **"uploads/user"admin.jpg**
This is my PHP to display the image.

```
<?php 
echo '<td class="col-md-3">  
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="' .$row2['buss_id'].'">' 
. '<img src=' . rawurldecode($row2['pic']) .'> '. $row2['username']; ?> </td>
```

To be more clear, this is how the string is being decoded in the browser

```
<img src="../uploads/user" admin.jpg>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing quotes. This part of your code:

```
'<img src=' . rawurldecode($row2['pic']) .'> '
```

should be this:

```
'<img src="' . rawurldecode($row2['pic']) .'"> '
```

---

The issue with your current code is that it emits something like this:

```
<img src=../uploads/user admin>
```

The browser treats the space as a separator between attributes, so it interprets that this way:

```
<img src="../uploads/user" admin>
```

Comment: "The browser treats the space as a separator between attributes" I see now. Thank you it worked. But now the image isn't showing because in the name it has the %20 part... Guess I'll need to find a way to deal with spaces differently.